# a https server based on cpp reports:alert certificate unknown:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 46

Tags: c, server, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

when I use Chrome to connect to my server, the server reports:
BC630000:error:0A000416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 46

this is the source code of my https server
working on Win10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#include "openssl/rsa.h"
#include "openssl/crypto.h"
#include "openssl/x509.h"
#include "openssl/pem.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
extern "C"
{
    #include <openssl/applink.c>
};
/*所有需要的参数信息都在此处以#define的形式提供*/
#define CERTF   "servercert.crt" /*服务端的证书(需经CA签名)*/
#define KEYF   "serverkey.pem"  /*服务端的私钥(建议加密存储)*/
#define CACERT "cacert.crt" /*CA 的证书*/
#define PORT   1111   /*准备绑定的端口*/

#define CHK_NULL(x) if ((x)==NULL) exit (1)
#define CHK_ERR(err,s) if ((err)==-1) { perror(s); exit(1); }
#define CHK_SSL(err) if ((err)==-1) { ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(2); }
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
int main ()
{
  int err;
  int listen_sd;
  int sd;
  struct sockaddr_in sa_serv;
  struct sockaddr_in sa_cli;
  int client_len;
  SSL_CTX* ctx;
  SSL*     ssl;
  X509*    client_cert;
  char*    str;
  char     buf [4096];
  const SSL_METHOD *meth;
  WSADATA wsaData;

  if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData) != 0){
    printf("WSAStartup()fail:%d\n",GetLastError());
    return -1;
  }

  SSL_load_error_strings();            /*为打印调试信息作准备*/
  OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();        /*初始化*/
  meth = SSLv23_server_method();  /*采用什么协议(SSLv2/SSLv3/TLSv1)在此指定*/

  ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);
  CHK_NULL(ctx);

  SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);   /*验证与否*/
  SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CACERT,NULL); /*若验证,则放置CA证书*/
SSL_CTX_set_security_level(ctx,1);
if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CERTF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(3);
  }
  if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEYF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(4);
  }

  if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
    printf("Private key does not match the certificate public key\n");
    exit(5);
  }

  SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"RC4-MD5");

  /*开始正常的TCP socket过程.................................*/
  printf("Begin TCP socket...\n");

  listen_sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  CHK_ERR(listen_sd, "socket");

  memset (&sa_serv, '/0', sizeof(sa_serv));
  sa_serv.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  sa_serv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  sa_serv.sin_port        = htons (PORT);

  err = bind(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa_serv,

sizeof (sa_serv));

CHK_ERR(err, "bind");

  /*接受TCP链接*/
  err = listen (listen_sd, 5);
  CHK_ERR(err, "listen");

  client_len = sizeof(sa_cli);
  sd = accept (listen_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa_cli, &client_len);
  CHK_ERR(sd, "accept");
  closesocket (listen_sd);

  printf ("Connection from %lx, port %x\n",
      sa_cli.sin_addr.s_addr, sa_cli.sin_port);


  printf("Begin server side SSL\n");

  ssl = SSL_new (ctx);
  CHK_NULL(ssl);
  SSL_set_fd (ssl, sd);
  err = SSL_accept (ssl);
  printf("SSL_accept finished\n");
  CHK_SSL(err);


  printf ("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher (ssl));


  client_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate (ssl);
  if (client_cert != NULL) {
    printf ("Client certificate:\n");

    str = X509_NAME_oneline (X509_get_subject_name (client_cert), 0, 0);
    CHK_NULL(str);
    printf ("\t subject: %s\n", str);

    str = X509_NAME_oneline (X509_get_issuer_name  (client_cert), 0, 0);
    printf ("\t issuer: %s\n", str);

    X509_free (client_cert);/*如不再需要,需将证书释放 */
  }
  else
    printf ("Client does not have certificate.\n");

  /* 数据交换开始,用SSL_write,SSL_read代替write,read */
  err = SSL_read (ssl, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
  CHK_SSL(err);
  buf[err] = '/0';
  printf ("Got %d chars:'%s'\n", err, buf);
  const char *response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello World!";
  err = SSL_write (ssl, response, strlen(response));
  CHK_SSL(err);

  /* 收尾工作*/
  shutdown (sd,2);
  SSL_free (ssl);
  SSL_CTX_free (ctx);

  return 0;
}
```

importing servercert.crt to my Chorme does not work.
What shoule I do to let my browser connect to my server?